# How to get data to controller when xml page refreshed in openui5

Tags: sapui5

I want to get data from controller when XML page was refreshed and that data coming from another page controller. Below as my code.

This one of the function in header.controller.js

```
categoryfunc: function (oEvent) {
        var CatId = oEvent.getSource().mProperties.target;
        if (CatId !== "") {
            leftmenudata = this.nav.ajaxactioncalls({
                url: serviceData.leftmenuinfo,
                data: {categoryId: CatId},
                type: "POST"
            });
            if (leftmenudata.length === 1) {
                leftmenudetail = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(leftmenudata.info);
                this.getView().setModel(leftmenudetail, "leftmenuinfo");
                var viewNavcontent = sap.ui.xmlview("acetrix.shopping.view.dashboard.navcontent");
                viewNavcontent.getController().leftmenufunc(leftmenudetail);
                var stockinfo = {stockdata: leftmenudata.info.stockdata};
                stockdetail = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(stockinfo);
                this.getView().setModel(stockdetail, "stockdetail");
                var dataa = {link: 'dashboard.cartitems', leftNav: true};
                this.nav.navPageTo(dataa);
            } else {
                var durationtime = Number(serviceData.popupduration);
                sap.m.MessageToast.show(leftmenudata.message, {duration: durationtime, at: "center top"});
                $(".sapMMessageToast").addClass("errormessagetoast");
            }
        }
    }
```

when click on menu link this function works and rendering to cartitems.view.xml. I'm calling data in controller which is related to this view like below:

```
onAfterRendering: function (oEvent) {
        var stockinfo = stockdetail.getData();
        cartinfo = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(stockinfo);
        this.getView().setModel(cartinfo, "stockdetail");
    }
```

It works on normal way but when I refreshed the page it gets an error like

> Error: stockdetail is undefined.

How will rectify this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that when you refresh the page `onAfterRendering` function is called before `categoryfunc` function; this causes the value undefined of `stockdetail` variable.

The rigth way to define a model is do it in `onInit` function that is automatically called before any other function in the controller